# Cant deploy project on Wildfly in standalone Keycloak

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I starting standalone Keycloak on Wildfly. 
Next i install keycloak-wildfly-adapter in my standalone keycloak folder (inside is include wildfly) with this command:

```
cd bin
./jboss-cli.sh --file=adapter-install-offline.cli
```

Then i want to deploy my app on server with this command:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy
```

and i get ERROR:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:107)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:135)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension.handleDeployment(KeycloakServletExtension.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:152)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more

16:11:31,347 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ldap-portal.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I"}}
16:11:31,349 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "ldap-portal.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ldap-portal: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig.getMinTimeBetweenJwksRequests()I"}}
```

Can someone explain me why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Thanks for posting a good question, very detailed. Just one thing was not clear to me, could you explain what you mean with "(inside is include wildfly)" in your first paragraph?

Comment: Hey. I mean that standalone keycloak have integrate wildfly. So in keycloak folder is wildfly to.

Comment: This looks like it might be a mismatch between two different versions of Keycloak.